# How to replace image by button to call onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using image button in jsp to call onclick function javascript, I call it via onclick and id:

```
<img src="<%= imagesDir%>/bt_pre.gif" onclick="return PreviousQ();" id="prevbtn" style="cursor: hand;">
```

with above line, code run good..
But I update it in tag button, it seem can not run and call onclick function javascript...

```
<button class="css-button-rounded" onclick="return PreviousQ();" id="prevbtn" style="cursor: hand;">Back question</button>
```

How to call onclick="return PreviousQ();" and id="prevbtn" ?

Thank so much !!

Comment: It should work. Look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/612s5f8e/. In your case, may be you have used the same id multiple times. cross check on that.

Comment: if your img and button have the same id you cannot do that, instead use a class

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that with jquery if i understand questions correctly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prevbtn").on('click',function(){
        $(this).prev();
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="http://s5.tinypic.com/15rf4zn_th.jpg"  id="prevbtn" style="cursor: hand;">

<button class="css-button-rounded" onclick="document.getElementById('prevbtn').src='http://s5.tinypic.com/vew3n7_th.jpg'"; >Back question</button>
```